# How do I split a name in a list then reinsert the split items?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list

I have lists inside the csv list:

```
newlist = [
    ['ï»¿id', 'name', 'lastContactedTime', 'email', 'phone_phones', 'home_phones', 'mobile_phones', 'work_phones', 'fax_phones', 'other_phones', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'address_3', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'country', 'tags'], 
    ['12-contacts', 'Courtney James', '', 'courtney@forlanchema.com', '+1 3455463849', '', '', '', '', '', '654 Rodney Franklin street', '', '', 'Birmingham', 'AL', '45678', 'US', ''], 
    ['4-contacts', 'Joe Malcoun', '2019-08-13 14:41:12', 'ceo@nutshell.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '212 South Fifth Ave', '', '', 'Ann Arbor', 'MI', '48103', 'US', ''], 
    ['8-contacts', 'Rafael Acosta', '', 'racosta@forlanchema.com', '+1 338551534', '', '', '', '', '', '13 Jordan Avenue SW', '', '', 'Birmingham', 'AL', '45302', 'US', '']
]
```

I want to create a recurring event where I split the names like: `"Courtney James"` in each list and add it to a new list.

I have tried to split and append each name separately using a while loop to a list but it did not work out

```
#Splitting an item in the list and adding it to a new list  
m = 1
while newlist[m][1] != None:
    splitter = newlist[m][1].split()
    namelist = splitter
    m+1

    print(namelist)
else:
    break
```

I get errors or the code does not compile. I expect the names to be split and added to a new list.

My desired output would be recurring lists to be able to add it to a new excel worksheet using xlsxwriter:
Headers= ['Lastname','First name','Company','Title','Willing To share', 'Willing to introduce', 'Work phone', 'Work email', 'Work street', 'Work City', ' Work State', 'Work Zip', 'Personal Street', 'Personal City', 'Personal State', 'Personal Zip', 'Mobile Phone', 'Personal email', 'Note', 'Note Category']
List1= ['Doe1', 'John', 'company1', 'CIO', 'Yes', 'Yes', '999-999-999', 'email@email.com', '123 work street', 'workville', 'IL', '12345', '1234 personal street', 'peronville', 'Il', '12345', '999-999-999', 'personemail@email.com', 'public note visible to everyone', 'Public']
List2=
List3=

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your expected output.

Comment: Also please post the actual error

Comment: `m+1` At the very least, I'm guessing you meant this to be `m += 1`

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split each name, you get a list such as `[first_name, last_name]`. Assuming you wanted to build up a "list of these lists", then you want to do the following using your code as a basis:

```
namelist = [] # new, empty list
for i in range(1, len(newlist)):
    names = newlist[i][1].split() # this yields [first_name, last_name]
    #print(names)
    namelist.append([names[1], names[0]]) # [last_name, first_name]
```

- `range(1, len(newlist))` generates the numbers 1, 2, ... length of newlist - 1
- `namelist.append([names[1], names[0]])` appends the split names to our new list

The result:

```
[['James', 'Courtney'], ['Malcoun', 'Joe'], ['Acosta', 'Rafael']]
```

What you are looking for is a more complicated list with other elements in it. But at least the above code shows how to properly loop through your original list.